# Ausdruck für vor langer Zeit angeeignetes fast-vergessenes Wissen

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche einen deutschen (idealerweise Lebenslauf-kompatiblen) Ausdruck, mit dem ich Wissen und Kenntnisse beschreiben kann, die ich mir vor langer Zeit angeeignet habe, aber mittlerweile teilweise vergessen habe bzw. eine Auffrischung notwendig wäre.

Beispiele:

- In der Schule gelernte, aber lange nicht benutzte Fremdsprachen.
- Während dem Studium gelernte Dinge, die danach jahrelang nicht mehr verwendet wurden.
- Domainspezifisches Wissen von vorhergehenden Arbeitsstellen etc.

Auf Englisch würde ich die Adjektive *dated* oder *dormant* verwenden.

Comment: Man kann sagen, dass man die "Grundlagen" weiß. Das sagt zwar nicht aus, ob man jemals mehr gelernt hat, aber es ist offensichtlich, dass man eben nicht bei Null anfängt, aber auch nicht volle Expertise aufweißt. Interessant ist übrigens in dem Zusammenhang der Begriff "fundiert". Menschen fassen den Begriff unterschiedlich auf. So kann je nach Verständnis das Wort hier ins Rennen geschickt werden; meinem persönlichen Verständnis nach jedoch ist der Begriff fehl am Platz.

Comment: @Em1 arved fragte nach "verblasstem Wissen", das einer Auffrischung bedarf - "Grundlagen" passt da m.A. nach nicht so richtig - Die kann ich nämlich alle "noch parat" haben oder fast alle vergessen haben - Gelernt habe ich aber beide "Sorten" (hoffentlich) mal gründlich.

Comment: Daß die Erlernung lange her ist und die Fertigkeit sehr beeinträchtigt ist, kann man mit *eingerostet* umschreiben.

Comment: Rein beruflich würde ich eher ganz stark davon abraten sowas überhaupt in den Lebenslauf hereinzunehmen. Altes, seit Jahren oder Jahrzehnten nicht mehr angewandte Kenntnisse interessieren heutzutage (leider?) keine mehr.

Answer (score 6):

Man könnte einen Ausdruck wie

> "inzwischen tief vergrabenes Wissen über..."

o.A. verwenden. Bei Sprachen passen Ausdrücke wie

> "gelernt, aber nicht/zu wenig angewendet/praktiziert".

(Den hast du ja schon selbst genannt)

Ich denke,

> "(teilweise) verblasstes Wissen in..."
>
> "auffrischungsbedürftig"

ist auch noch brauchbar. Alle sind weniger treffend, aber eher "lebenslaufgeeignet" als *eingerostet* (das m.A. nach immer noch der treffendste Begriff ist). *auffrischungsbedürftig* gefällt mir danach übrigens für deinen Zweck am besten.

Comment: Verblasst finde ich ja in Ordnung, aber vergraben?

Comment: @userunknown Warum nicht? Ich zitiere mal "Duden Praxis - EInstellungstests sicher bestehen" (weil's so schön zum Thema passt): *... die oft sogar noch tief im Unterbewusstsein vergrabenes Wissen an die Oberfläche bringen...* als eine von vielen Fundstellen.

Comment: Im Unterbewusstsein ist kein Wissen vergraben, sondern Wünsche und Triebe, falls es für die Inkompetenz des Dudens noch eines Beleges bedurft hat. Aber es geht ja um Sprache, nicht Psychoanalyse. Wenn etwas vergraben ist gräbt man einmalig danach, und es liegt wieder zutage - soll das wirklich gemeint sein? Man ist doch aus der Übung und out of date.

Comment: Ich denke sogar, dass **genau das** in einer Bewerbung gemeint sein könnte. Man will ja sagen "Konnte ich mal, braucht nur ein bisschen Auffrischung, und alles ist wieder da" anstatt "Habe ich alles verlernt". Ansonsten würde man es ja nicht erwähnen.

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort

> angestaubt

halte ich für eine lebenslauf-taugliche Lösung, in der auch gleich mitschwingt, dass es mit etwas Arbeit ganz präsentabel werden kann. Ich habe außerdem noch *latentes Wissen* in Betracht gezogen, aber nach einigen Recherchen als unpassenden Fachbegriff verworfen.

Comment: "angestaubt" nutzt man im deutschen eher für Subjekte, zum Beispiel eine Vase. Aber nicht für "Wissen", erst recht nicht im Lebenslauf.

Comment: @membersound [Wortschatz Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=22&Wort_id=6864879&bl=208) hat aber mehr Beispiele für die übertragene Bedeutung.

Comment: Trotzudem ist "angestaub" in einem Lebenslauf absolut unangebracht.

Answer (score 1):

Eine nur bedingt Lebenslauf-geeignete Möglichkeit ist ***eingerostet**,* z. B.:

> Mein Altgriechisch ist etwas eingerostet.
>
> Fremdsprachen: Englisch, Altgriechisch (etwas eingerostet), Französisch.

Answer (score 0):

Meines Wissens nach gibt es übliche Begriffe wie "Englisch verhandlungssicher" oder "Französisch Grundkenntnisse". Dann weiß jeder, dass sich der Bewerber mit Mühe ein Baguette bestellen kann.

Hinsichtlich anderem Wissen würde ich dann erwähnen, dass ich es im Studium gelernt, seither aber nicht mehr angewendet habe, oder eben auch von Grundkenntnissen sprechen. Wenn ich schreibe, dass ich vor zehn Jahren mal zwei Jahre mit Oracle gearbeitet habe, kann der andere einschätzen, was er davon hält, zumal ich mich ja auch nur auf entsprechende Ausschreibungen bewürbe.

Comment: +1 für den schönen Konjunktiv II *bewürbe*! Ist mir schon sehr lange nicht mehr begegnet.

Comment: *verhandlungssicher* oder *Grundkenntnisse* kann aber auch heißen, dass ich gerade einen Crash-Kurs hinter mir habe. Wenn ich hingegen in der Schule neun Jahre Französisch samt einem Austauschjahr hatte, habe ich in der Regel mehr als Grundkenntnisse; trotzdem kann es sein, dass ich diese Kenntnisse seitdem praktisch nicht mehr genutzt habe.

Answer (score -2):

Vielleicht wäre `rudimentär` eine Möglichkeit bzw. `inzwischen rudimentär`.

Comment: *rudimentär* bedeutet u.a. auch "unvollständig" oder "unzureichend" - Ich glaube nicht, dass das etwas ist, was der OP in seinem Lebenslauf stehen haben will... Er möchte ja ausdrücken "Ich hab's mal gekonnt und brauche nur eine kleine Auffrischung, bis ich darin wieder perfekt bin"

Answer (score -2):

Für den Lebenslauf brauchst du ein Wort, das nicht Umgangssprache ist. Es eignet sich z.B. "Grundkenntnisse".

Man kann zwar auch sagen "Wissen verblasst", aber im Lebenslauf wirkt das unprofessionell.

Comment: Siehe [meinen Kommentar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29278/ausdruck-f%c3%bcr-vor-langer-zeit-angeeignetes-fast-vergessenes-wissen/29405#comment71739_29290) auf Veredomons Antwort.